# Is there a supermassive black hole at the Galactic Core?

Tags: star-wars

In our universe there are [supermassive black holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermassive_black_hole) at the center of (most? all?) galaxies.

Is there such a black hole at the Galactic Core in the Star Wars universe?  And if so what effect does it have on Coruscant and other core worlds?  And if not, is there any explanation (in universe) about why?  (Obviously the real explanation may just be that we didn't know about these black holes when the SW universe was invented, but that's not very interesting)

I will accept information from any level of canon, even fan fiction, I'm just curious if this has been leveraged in SW...

[image]
[image from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Artist%27s_impression_of_the_surroundings_of_the_supermassive_black_hole_in_NGC_3783.jpg)

Comment: Give me a day to write a slashfic about supermassive black whole and Anakin Skywalker.

Comment: Is he looking for love in Alderaan places?

Comment: This is also confirmed in the Darth Bane novels. Probably not worth adding an answer for though.

Comment: By a process of extrapolation, I predict a future Star Wars movie featuring a bad guy wearing black who has built a gigantic super-weapon, which can harness the energy of the galactic super black hole (and yet amazingly not be affected by the gravitational effects) and is able to vapourise entire star systems with a single shot. However, it will have one critical weakness that will allow a troubled young hero to destroy it simply by sneaking in and asking its central computer to solve an impossible computation....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*The Essential Atlas* is your friend. It mentions that there is one:

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Center

> The Galactic Center was a supermassive black hole that existed at the center of the galaxy. Its mass was estimated to be four million stellar masses. While no living sentient had ever witnessed it firsthand, probe droids had been sent to observe and confirm its existence.

This was also mentioned in a couple of C level canon works, listed in the Wikia article above.

Also, related: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Core

Comment: thanks, I read the galactic core article but it doesn't mention the black hole directly.

Comment: @zipquincy 'The Deep Core was home to some thirty billion of the galaxy's oldest stars, and at its center was a massive black hole surrounded by antimatter and dense clusters where stars were only a hundredth of a light year apart'

Comment: Poor probe droids. That sounds like a really crappy job.

Answer (score 3):

**Disney Canon**

***Battlefront: Twilight Company***

> He'd spoken of a singularity in the galactic Deep Core. In the middle
>   of everything, Gadren said, there was a black hole that devoured all
>   light and energy, exerting a gravitational pull more powerful than a
>   thousand suns.  - p. 187 digital