# Black Holes in Star Wars

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, black-hole

Black holes are a pretty common feature in science fiction, whether for warping, power generation, etc. However, I can't recall any mention of them in Star Wars.

**Are there any notable mentions of black holes in the Star Wars?** Official Canon is preferred, but Legends and such are fine.

Comment: Didn't Han mention black holes as one of the reasons nav computers take a while to calculate a hyperspace route?

Comment: @WadCheber: Apparently, he only mentions [a star and a supernova](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcX8mDRIhYE).

Comment: They're definitely in legends, e.g. The Maw (where the Death Star was designed) is a black hole cluster in the vicinity of Kessel.

Comment: @WadCheber I remembered that, but wasn't positive about it.

Comment: Related: [Is there a supermassive black hole at the galactic core?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47830/is-there-a-supermassive-black-hole-at-the-galactic-core)

Comment: @Ellesedil My answer addresses that one, confirmed in the Darth Bane novels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Legends Answer:

I only know of 2 books that mention them, *Star Wars: Into the Void* and *Darth Bane: Rule of two*.

In *Star Wars: Into the Void* the protagonists are trying to stop the antagonist from activating an ancient Gree device that would create a black hole,

> It could destroy Tython," Dam-Powl said. "Exposing dark matter to normal matter would be cataclysmic. It would create a **black hole**, swallowing Tython in a heartbeat. The rest of the system, too."
>
> *Star Wars: Into the Void* page 16,   25 793 BBY

and

> "He's going to kill everyone, " seh said. "Once he initiates the device, the dark matter will form a **black hole** and everyone in the system-"
>
> *Star Wars: Into the Void* page 185,   25 793 BBY

In the *Darth Bane series* they are searching for an ancient temple located on Tython (though 20 000+ years *after Into the Void*) which is near a black hole.

> "Tython?" Zannah exclaimed, recognizing the name. "Isn't that one of the Deep Core worlds?"
>
> The Deep Core was a small cluster of densely packed stars centered on a **black hole** in the very heart of the galaxy.
>
> *Darth Bane: Rule of two* Page ???, ~1000 BBY

[image]
Everything within this core zone is a high security zone where travel is restricted due to the black hole and other shifting gravitational anomalies.

This black hole near Tython is the galactic core black hole mentioned in [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47830/is-there-a-supermassive-black-hole-at-the-galactic-core) answer.

Comment: There are way more than that, The Maw is a cluster of black holes and it's in many books. Probably 15+.

Comment: @Probst Yah I didn't say there wasn't, The books I've read only mentioned 1 though.

Answer (score 8):

In Canon, I can only think of 1 semi-example.

In the *Star Wars Rebels* episode [*Legends of the Lasat*](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/star-wars-rebels/legends-of-the-lasat-episode-guide) (Season 2, episode 14), the crew of the Ghost encounter an "imploded star cluster". I'm not sure what exactly an imploded star cluster is, but it sounds like a high-gravity area and the closest thing I know of to a black hole depicted in a Disney canon work.

In Legends, the answer is much more clear. There is [the Maw](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Maw) which is a cluster of black holes. In and around the Maw resides various stations including the [Maw Installation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maw_Installation) which was a secret weapons development station utilized by the Empire located inside of the black hole cluster.

Answer (score 4):

**This is a Legend answer.**

The first thing that comes to my mind is **the Maw**. The Maw is a black hole cluster located in the Outer Rim near Kessel. This is where the Empire built partially the Death Star I and other weapons, like the Sun Crusher (from the Jedi Academy trilogy). 
The area is used in later novels, especially in Fate of the Jedi series where we learn that

> the Maw was created to be a prison for the dark side entity Abeloth

Source: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Maw

There is a great retcon with the movies and the Maw black hole cluster: smugglers used to fly near the Maw to avoid Imperial patrols. That's how the Millenium Falcon did the Kessel Run in less than 12 parsecs - basically flying near the black holes reduces the distance. More details here: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kessel_Run/Legends

There are several other black holes in Legends, like the Galactic Center. You can find a list here: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Black_hole

Answer (score 3):

**Disney Canon**

***Star Wars: Heir to the Jedi***

> The problem with conspiracy theories is that they have their own
>   gravity: they are black holes from which one rarely escapes
>    - Drusil (p. 176, digital)

Both statements are said in-universe by characters

> Merely thinking that refilled the empty space in the Force with even
>   more rage, and I saw what kind of space it was, a black hole that
>   would always be hungry no matter how much I fed it.
>   - Luke (p. 256, digital)

***Aftermath***

> The last thing Wedge wants to do is pilot around the edge of a black
>   hole or through the center of a star going supernova
>   - strange narrator, digital edition

***Battlefront: Twilight Company***

> He'd spoken of a singularity in the galactic Deep Core. In the middle
>   of everything, Gadren said, there was a black hole that devoured all
>   light and energy, exerting a gravitational pull more powerful than a
>   thousand suns. p. 187 digital

No explicit references in *Dark Disciple*, *A New Dawn*, *Lords of the Sith*, or *Tarkin*

Comment: Can't we pretend like *Tarkin* isn't canon?